# How can I lookup a value in a column for multiple rows?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, vlookup

I have a table with a column giving week number (1-52) in Column A, and I would like to get an average of all items listed in Column D of the same table.  So every week is represented by 5 rows.

The problem is that I if I use VLOOKUP, it gives me only the first row it encounters showing that data.  I would instead like to get all 5 rows of data from Column D, and average them.

I've tried

```
=AVERAGE(VLOOKUP(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21)-1,*TableName*[[*1stColName*]:[*4thColName*]],4,FALSE))
```

&

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($D$1:$D$201,MATCH(WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21)-1,$A$1:$A$201,0)))
```

The problem is that each of these base formula's (without the average) only gives the first row encountered when starting from the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vlookup and Index/Match only ever return one value.

You can use AverageIF (or even AverageIFS if you have multiple criteria), in Excel 2007 and up.

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$20,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21),$C$2:$C$20)
```

With earlier versions, you can use this array formula, which must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$20=WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21),$C$2:$C$20))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked pretty decent.  Altered a little bit, but essentially I used it as:
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIF($A:$A,WEEKNUM(TODAY(),21),$D:$D),0)

Can I also do this for Median value?

Comment: Please mark the post as the answer as explained in the [Tour]. There is no MedianIF, so you will need to use the second approach with the array formula, using Median instead of Average. Remember Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Be aware that you don't want to use whole column references with array formulas. It will take forever to calculate.